# Android Java version and using compileWith. Are there better alternatives on how to do this?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-manifest

I've got the following code in my AndroidManifest.xml file.

```
android {
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    compileSdkVersion 33
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.ccc.ddd"
        minSdkVersion 26
        targetSdkVersion 33
        versionCode 7
        versionName "1.6"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        compileOptions.with {
            sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
            targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        merge 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    }
}
```

However, i am unable to understand the Java versions referenced here. What does this mean?

```
compileOptions.with {
                sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
                targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
            }
```

What's the latest Java version for Android, and does it really matter?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

For Android API level, use the compileSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion options, and for Java language level, use the sourceCompatibility and targetCompatibility options.

Comment: Yes, but what do those terms mean?

Comment: The context is unclues. Please add some more information like api version other config information as well as some code you tried if you have it.

Answer (score 0):

1. JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8

This signifies the java version you want, the above is java version 8, for java version 10 it will be: JavaVersion.VERSION_1_10

2. sourceCompatibility vs targetCompatibility

targetCompatibility and sourceCompatibility maps to -target release and -source release in javac. Source is basically the source language level and target is the level of the bytecode that is generated.